# Plot only some values of a column

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

is it possible to plot only some values of a column, like the first 10 of 100 or even only values of line 50 to 60?

Comment: reproducible example please?

Comment: Just take a subset of the data, see `?[` or `?subset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plot(column_x[1:10])
plot(column_x[50:60])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer rather quick [here](http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html). It would have been `x <- df$variable[1:10]`.

Comment: That would be the first 10 columns, not the first 10 values in a column.

Comment: How can I than, for example, address the first 10 values in a column?